# rubyのselfは何が言いたいのかわからない。

Tags: ruby

selfはメソッドの中で呼び出すと、メソッドを実行している、インスタンス自身となり、それはtomになります。tomのことをレシーバーといいます。tomにはUser.new('tom')というインスタンスが代入されいて、最終的にはselfはUser.newを指していることだと思います。

つまりは　「def initialize(name)メソッドはインスタンス変数を保持しており、**.nameメソッドでアクセサを参照し保持されたインスタンス変数を見にいくから**、
hi I am tomになる」ということで宜しいでしょうか？

```
 class User
      attr_accessor :name

      def initialize(name)
        @name = name
      end

      def sayHi
        self　#self.nameがわからない
        puts "hi I am #{self.name}"#なぜself.nameでtomに？
      end
    end

    tom = User new("tom")
    tom.sayHi
```

#### 分かったこと

1. p self → User:0x00000000057c4098 @name="tom"
   インスタンス変数を自動的に見ている。
2. 1.の結果からselfはオブジェクトを見ている。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tomにはUser.new('tom')というインスタンスが代入されいて、最終的にはselfはUser.newを指していることだと思います。

`User.new`を指すというか、`User.new`によって生成されたオブジェクトを指します。

このオブジェクトは`new`の引数として`"tom"`を渡しており、結果[initialize](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Object/i/initialize.html)メソッドに`"tom"`が渡ります。

少し書き換えて実験してみました

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def sayHi
    self #self.nameがわからない
    puts "#{@name}: hi I am #{self.name}"#なぜself.nameでtomに？
  end

  # selfを他のオブジェクトと比べてみる
  def eq?(obj)
    puts "#{self.name} == #{obj.name}: #{obj == self}"
  end
end

user_tom = User.new("tom")
user_tom.sayHi
# 以下ちょい蛇足self(レシーバー)とは何か実験してみる
p user_tom
user_tom.eq?(user_tom)
user_tom.eq?(User.new("bob"))
```

**追記**

> selfはなぜこれを使うのか？という疑問

逆にないと、常に記憶喪失な人に「お前はトムだが挨拶しろ」みたいになって不便だと思います

`self.name`じゃなくて`@name`でいいのでは？というのなら例が悪いかなと思います。

`self.name`じゃなくて`name`でいいのではないか？(暗黙のself)というのなら、好みですね

`name = "slime"` とした時にローカル変数なのかアクセッサの呼び出しなのか分からずに、
ローカル変数への代入として処理されるRubyの仕様があるので
個人的にはselfの省略は好きではないです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。user_tom.eq?(user_tom)でなぜobjがtomになっているのかわかりませんでした。selfは単にレシーバーを参照しているだけでそれ以上に深い意味はないものと認識しておこうと思います。どちらかというとnameメソッドのほうが重要だと思いました。

Comment: selfはなぜこれを使うのか？という疑問があるかぎり、ずっと解決しないとかんじました。selfはメソッド内で使うためと認識しておこうと思いますが、おそらく自分はまだ全然修行がたりないですね。出直してきます

Answer (score 1):

ruby はオブジェクト指向プログラミング言語です。関数は実は存在していなくって、ありとあらゆる関数っぽいものは、実は何かしらのメソッドです。メソッドのロジックを`def`などで記述している段階では、なので必ず暗黙的に今そのメソッドを実行しようとしているオブジェクトというものが想定できるはずです。これが `self` です。

ruby は、メソッドのロジックにおいて、ローカル変数でない名前を発見すると、それはメソッドであると解釈して、 `self.メソッド` を呼ぶんだな、と判断します。

```
puts "hi I am #{self.name}"
```

たとえば上記の puts は、 Object クラスのプライベートメソッドです。(プライベートメソッドは、レシーバーを指定する形の呼び出しができないタイプのメソッドなので、 `self.puts "hoge"` は実行できないですが。。)

---

attr_accessor は, ruby のメタプログラミング的な何かです。 `attr_accessor シンボル` の効用は、

```
def シンボル
    @シンボル
end

def シンボル=(v)
    @シンボル = v
end
```

とざっくり等価です。 self.name は、 `name` メソッドが呼びだされ、その中でインスタンス変数が読み込まれ、返り値として取得されます。 `name` メソッドは、プライベートメソッドではないので、 self を省略した形式でも呼び出すことができます。ちなみに、セッターメソッドは、その言語仕様的に、ローカル変数の代入と区別ができなくなってしまうので、これにかぎり、 `self.name = 値` の形式で記述する必要があります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。これから書くことは不愉快に思われるかもしれませんが、この回答に書いてあることは書籍にもそれらしきことは書いてあります。どういう動きをするのかはわかったけども、それ以上の理解は進まないという感じです。努力が足りないですね。

Comment: @matomebutai うーん、なるほど。。スタックオーバーフローでは、その性質上、質問を行えるぐらいには自分の中で対象ドメインについて知っていた方が良い、という構造があります。もし、体系的な知識を一括で学びたいのであれば、例えば メタプログラミング ruby などを読んで見るのがいいかもしれないです。